# Create a WAR file with version using ANT

Tags: java, ant, jboss

I have a problem trying to build a WAR file with a version number.
This is my build.properties

> jboss.home=D\:\java\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final
>
> version=2.0

And this is part of my ANT task

```
<project name="AS2-jBoss7" basedir="../" default="deploy">

<!-- Configuraciones del proyecto -->
<property name="project.distname" value="AS2" />

<!-- Paths locales del sistema -->
<property file="${basedir}/ant/build.properties" />
<property name="webroot.dir" value="${basedir}/WebContent" />
<property name="webinf.dir" value="${webroot.dir}/WEB-INF" />
<property name="build.dir" value="build" />

<!-- Build project -->
<target name="build" depends="prepare,compile" />
<target name="rebuild" depends="clean,prepare,compile" />

<!-- Crea el war de la aplicacion -->
<target name="war" depends="build">
<mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
<war basedir="${webroot.dir}" warfile="${build.dir}/${project.distname}_${version}.war"  webxml="${webinf.dir}/web.xml">
<exclude name="WEB-INF/${build.dir}/**" />
<exclude name="WEB-INF/otros/**" />
</war>
</target>

<!-- Despliega el proyecto -->
<target name="deploy" depends="war">
<delete file="${deploy.dir}/${project.distname}.war" />
<delete dir="${deploy.dir}/${project.distname}" />
<copy file="${build.dir}/${project.distname}_${version}.war" todir="${deploy.dir}" />
</target>
</project>
```

When I build my WAR file the name is AS2_2.0.war and that is correct, but when I view the site in the web browser I have to write the url:

```
http://localhost:8030/AS2_2.0/login.jsf
```

What I want is that the WAR version is AS2_2.0 but the URL does not contain the version number, how could I do that?

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/guides/webguide/r2/en/html/ch06.html

Comment: Now I got another problem: AS2/ServicioUsuarioImpl -- service jboss.naming.context.java.app."AS2-1.0".AS2.ServicioUsuarioImpl Why happens this?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with ANT, your application server is using the name of the WAR by default. What you want to do is change the "context root" for your web application. If you Google that phrase, along with the name of your application server (e.g. "Tomcat" or "JBoss"), I'm sure you'll find your answer. Or, if you tell me what server you're using I can try and help you.

Comment: Thank you, the server is Jboss AS 7.1.1

Comment: Thank you I found the answer as you told me. What I made was to create a jboss-web.xml in WEB-INF with this content:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_5_1.xsd">
   <context-root>/AS2</context-root>
</jboss-web>
And it worked perfect. Thank you very much

Comment: Now I got another problem:
 AS2/ServicioUsuarioImpl -- service jboss.naming.context.java.app."AS2-1.0".AS2.ServicioUsuarioImpl
Why happens this?

Answer (score 0):

See http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html In examples, you can copy a single file with ant just like this,

```
 <copy file="myfile.txt" tofile="mycopy.txt"/>
```

In your case supposing you want the deployed file to be named `AS` try

```
<target name="deploy" depends="war">
  <delete file="${deploy.dir}/${project.distname}/AS.war" />
  <delete dir="${deploy.dir}/${project.distname}" />
  <copy file="${build.dir}/${project.distname}_${version}.war" tofile="${deploy.dir}/AS.war" />
</target>
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to keep the name AS_version_number.war but the URL doesn't contain the version_number